# Restore Adapter's SparseBooleanArray of FragmentA when moving to FragmentB and back with Back Button?

Tags: java, android-studio, listview, fragment

I have two Fragments. Both have a ListView and a UserAdapter. The ListView of `Fragment B` consists of the selected ListItems of `Fragment A`. The currently checked (selected) ListItems in both Fragments are held in a `SparseBooleanArray selectedIds`.

I navigate between the Fragments by `Navigation Component` and pass an array, which I get by reading out the `SparseBooleanArray` values:

```
FragmentADirections.ActionFragmentAToFragmentB action = FragmentADirections.actionFragmentAToFragmentB(array);
Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(action);
```

The `ListView` Items have an attached selector for their background drawable. I toggle the checked state with the following code (it's a self written method within the adapter class):

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener((new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            adapter.toggleSelection(position);
        }
```

**Question:** How to save and restore the `SparseBooleanArray` of `FragmentA` when moving to `FragmentB` and back with the `Back Button`? The ListItem's background state remains checked but my `SparseBooleanArray` is empty. I want the `SparseBooleanArray` to be filled as before.

***Idea:*** It might be because I am always creating a new adapter in the `onViewCreated()` method and my `SparseBooleanArray` exists within the adapter? How do I restore it?

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    adapter = new UserAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.list_item, userList);
}
```

Comment: This looks like C#. It might help if you tagged the language in your question.

Comment: @robbpriestley Thanks for the information, i've added it.